# Android drawing application need to change pencile width but it apply to entire drawing rather than next point drawing

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-seekbar

I am doing app like drawing app... All thing is working good.. But Now i want to add width of pencil..

For that ii have done

mPaint.setStrokeWidth(seekbarvalue);

But the problem is that it applying to untire drawing but i want to apply it on the next drawing only... What i should so?

My code is

```
private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath = new Path();
            paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, color, false));

        }

        private void drawText(int x, int y) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Here");
            Log.v(TAG, "X " + x + " Y " + y);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            paths.add(new PathPoints(color, textToDraw, true, x, y));
            // mCanvas.drawText(textToDraw, x, y, mPaint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            isTouched = true;
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (!isTextModeOn) {
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (!isTextModeOn) {
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (isTextModeOn) {
                    drawText((int) x, (int) y);
                    invalidate();
                } else {
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

And this is seekbaar

```
sekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser) {

                 mPaint.setStrokeWidth(progress);
                }
            }
        });
```

But it applies on entire drawing

and this is my ondraw mwthod

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas1) {
            canvas = canvas1;

            // === canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            invalidate();
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(GlobalVar.getSeekvalue());
            invalidate();
            canvas.drawBitmap(Transparent, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap2, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            // canvas.drawBitmap(Transparent, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            // canvas.drawBitmap(Transparent, 0, 0, null);
            // c2.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            for (PathPoints p : paths) {
                mPaint.setColor(p.getColor());

                Log.v("", "Color code : " + p.getColor());
                if (p.isTextToDraw()) {
                    canvas.drawText(p.textToDraw, p.x, p.y, mPaint);
                } else {
                    // if(isTouched)
                    // {
                    // canvas.drawPath(p.getPath(), mPaint);

                    c2.drawPath(p.getPath(), mPaint);
```

what is i need to do?

Comment: create a new paint with that width and use it

Comment: can you elaborate it how? or some example

Comment: it's easy on your onProgressChanged instead change width stroke you need to instantiate a new paint

Comment: no not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set another field in PathPoint object and name it strokWidth and :

```
private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        int strokWidth = GlobalVar.getSeekvalue();  
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokWidth);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, color, false));

    }
```

and change every

```
paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, color, false));
```

to

```
paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, color, false,strokWidth));
```

now in ondraw method and in for loop :

```
for (PathPoints p : paths) {
            mPaint.setColor(p.getColor());
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(p.getStrokWidth());
```

now I think these lines are useless:

```
invalidate();
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(GlobalVar.getSeekvalue());
invalidate();
```

Comment: I wonder why? because as you store color for different paths separately you can also store the stroke width for them separately. I think the whole logic is true !!

Comment: But with little prob is that it is does work after 2 times changing seekbar value or touch_down method 2 times call

Comment: because in onTouch up method you have not update the stroke width of mPaint

Comment: i am not getting... i mean what should i do to overcome it?

Comment: My final answer is here.

Comment: I removed my touch down method and update the touch up, did you notice it

Comment: strokWidth = GlobalVar.getSeekvalue();
   mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokWidth);
   mPath.reset();
   mPath.moveTo(x, y);
   paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, color, false, strokWidth));
   mX = x;
   mY = y;

Comment: OKKKK WORKING  NOW ::)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pool of paints with diferent sroke (IMPORTANT:) make that in discrete parts.
 width por 4px, 8px, 12px,14px,18px and 22px.

```
 Paint basePaint=new Paint();

 SparseArray<Paint>poolPaint=new SparseArray<Paint>();

 Paint currPaint; //<- that's your paint that change width stroke on progressbar seek




 sekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
             // make it discrete not like here for every single width is not worthy
            int widthPaint=progress;
            if (fromUser) {
                if((currPaint=poolPaint.get(widthPaint))==null){
                      Paint newPaint=  new Paint(basePaint).setStrokeWidth(widthPaint)
                      poolPaint.put(widthPaint,newPaint);
                      currPaint=newPaint;  
                 }


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if((currPaint=poolPaint.get(widthPaint)==null))... this line not working.. mean red lines

Comment: brackets are not in the correct position look up the answer